Flutter - Modifying Dart lib
I am using the WebSocket class from dart:io in my project, and I want to make a small change in how it works. Specifically I want to add the response status code in the error that is thrown when the .connect() method fails (there's actually a pull request for this but it seems to have stalled). My issue is that I'm not sure how to modify dart source code on my end, in general.
VSCode tells me that what I'm looking for is defined at <flutter directory>/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/_http/websocket_impl.dart, however when I edit (or even completely delete!) this file it has no effect on the app when I build the apk. So clearly it's sourcing it from somewhere else? There's also a copy of the libs at <flutter directory>/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_http but changing these has no effect either. I also looked at AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev but I couldn't even find the file I wanted here. In the past I've modified external packages located in that last pub.dev directory and it's worked as expected, but I guess the built-in Dart libraries are different. I also restarted VSCode, my OS, and ran flutter clean to clear anything cached but that didn't work either. So, how do I go about doing this?

There are a few ways to be done.

First, since there is a pull request you can point the package to load from a specific git snapshot.

dependencies:
  # hosted in remote version control (ex: github)
  package_name:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/repo-name/project-name.git
      ref: ea12e41    # commit hash 
      ref: develop    # or branch name


Another way, local source, clone the source code and add the modification that you want then let pubspec.yml point to the local package. You might also push your modified code to github to allow others using it instead of distr

dependencies:
  # local source
  package_name:
    path: /path/to/your/local/repo/my_local_package


Moreover, depends on the change you can utilize extensions (docs) dart feature which allows you to add more functionalities or modify behaviors against code that you don't own.


Well it's not really a package per se, it appears to be part of the Dart SDK itself, so I think I would actually have to rebuild the entire SDK from source to change it, which is also why editing the source code did nothing...
